# wmic process not working using staf

Tags: windows, automation, wmic, staf

Why do I not get a proper list of processes below?
staf is running on remoteVM with correct trust levels.

```
[user@system ~]# staf remoteVM PROCESS START SHELL COMMAND "wmic process" WAIT RETURNSTDOUT STDERRTOSTDOUT
Response
--------
{
  Return Code: 0
  Key        : <None>
  Files      : [
    {
      Return Code: 0
      Data       :  ■C
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with this workaround ..

```
staf remoteVM PROCESS START SHELL COMMAND "WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\\ProcessList.txt PROCESS" WAIT RETURNSTDOUT STDERRTOSTDOUT
staf remoteVM PROCESS START SHELL COMMAND "type C:\\ProcessList.txt" WAIT RETURNSTDOUT STDERRTOSTDOUT
```